# Magento - how to include javascript file on a page by page basis

Tags: javascript, xml, layout, module, magento

In magento I know how to include js files in the page layout file.  How though, do i include specific javascript files only on certain pages with my custom module.
For example i am writing a custom module that will work with the product view and list pages.  I therfore want to have some sort of layout update that i can use with my module that will include my javascript file only on the product view and list pages.

Comment: can you provide examples of what pages you want them included on?

Comment: Hi thanks,  yeah the two pages i want to include them on are the /catalog/category/view and catalog/product/view pages.

Answer (score 18):

you will need to add a layout update section to your modules config file.  based on what you have said you will need something like this in your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
         <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>yourscript.js</script></action>
            </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

    <catalog_category_view>
           <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>yourscript.js</script></action>
            </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>

</layout>
```

Then in your modules config file, you will need something like:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
           <yourmodule>
               <file>yourlayout.xml</file>
            </yourmodule>
         </updates>
     </layout>
 </frontend>
```

This assumes that yourscript.js is sitting in the root of the js folder.  Obviously, you dont want to put it here so do what Jonathan advised and use:

```
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>path/file.js</name></action>
```

and put your js in your themes skin folder.

Good luck!

Comment: Do I need a router for it to work? A simple extension doing just that doesn't seem to be working here. I tried dropping the layout.xml file in the default theme folder and in the current theme folder and magento just won't go look for it. the javascript file is at the javascript root folder, not the themes ones.

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is find the layout handles for the pages that you want to include the JS, and add them to your custom module's layout XML.  For instance, to include the JS on the product view, you would add the following node to your layout:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>path/file.js</script></action>  **OR**
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>path/file.js</name></action>
  </reference>
```

Choose either option depending on where your JS files live.  Have a look in the default catalog.xml or review.xml for examples.

To work out the layout handle (e.g. catalog_product_view), you can use Alan Storm's excellent (and free) LayoutViewer module from his blog.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Thats kind of what i have been doing but it aint working.  Will magento load all layout.xml files it finds in the current theme and process them?  For example say i just dump a layout file in the base/default theme called mymodule.xml and include a reference as above, will magento process that?

Comment: If you want to quickly through something in a theme layout then call the file local.xml, Magento will always check for that last. I find it especially useful for taking advantage of inheritance in non-default themes.